# Simple "Where" Clause for "DateTime" comparison

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am trying to see whether a `Person` was older than a certain age at a specific point in time.

So currently `specificTime` is a `DATETIME` attritube and it has a value of `'2011-05-21'`

The `Age` is also a `DATETIME` attribute.

Does anyone have any ideas to a query that will determine whether the `Age` of a person is `greater than 15 years` old at the `specificTime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
select * from Person where (datediff(specificTime,Age) / 365) > 15
```

For more details on datetime functions refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
select * from person
where date_sub(specificTime,interval 15 years) > age;
```

first it will subtract the 15 years from '2011-05-21' i.e '1996-05-21' and after that it will compare that date to the age.

if the age_date is less than what is being specified by the date_sub means the person is born before 15 years and is older than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Age by this

```
<?php 
         //date in mm/dd/yyyy format; or it can be in other formats as well
         $birthDate = "12-17-1983";
         //explode the date to get month, day and year
         $birthDate = explode("-", $birthDate);
         //get age from date or birthdate
         $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $birthDate[0], $birthDate[1], $birthDate[2]))) > date("md") ? ((date("Y")-$birthDate[2])-1):(date("Y")-$birthDate[2]));
         echo "Age is:".$age;
    ?>
```

by this we can fine the age. Here  $birthDate i gave as Static but for your condition get from database and save it in $birthDate. I hope this will useful for you

Comment: -1.  The OP is clearly looking for SQL to use to find all of the person records who were less than 15 years old on a specific date.  This is PHP code that doesn't do that, it merely calculates the current age of a single person.